# How to print as a side-effect in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm recreating the popular word game "Wordle" in Elixir. I want to give the user feedback if they don't type in a 5 letter word. so far I've got this:

```
  def play do
    guess = IO.gets("Guess a 5 letter word: ")
    guess = String.trim(guess)
    guess = String.downcase(guess)
    attempt(guess)
  end

  def attempt(@correct_word) do
    "You won!"
  end

  def attempt(guess) when byte_size(guess) != 5 do
    "Guess must be 5 letters"
    play()
  end

  def attempt(guess) when byte_size(guess) == 5 do
    determine_guess_result(guess)
    "You have x guesses left"
  end
```

the problem is that this line never shows: `"Guess must be 5 letters"` because I immediately call `play()` after so it's never returned from the function

how is this achieve in Elixir where I can show this line and then call `play()` again to give the user the next turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`IO.puts/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#puts/2), which prints with a newline appended by default.

```elixir
IO.puts("Guess must be 5 letters")
play()
```